# How do I split a string by numbers while keep the numbers in the first location of each substring?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string like this:

`1a2b3c4def`

I want to split it into the following substrings, or an array:

1. `1a`
2. `2b`
3. `3c`
4. `4debf`

Every substring should start with a number character.

Another example:

Input: `1fw3fe.w6=3\657`

Output:

1. `1fw`
2. `3fe.w`
3. `6=`
4. `3\`
5. `6`
6. `5`
7. `7`

If there is no number in the string, then do nothing.

What functions should I choose?

Update:

No more specific rules, just random input. I forgot to mention, the first character will ALWAYS be a digit. So if there are no more digits, put the whole string in an array.

Comment: What are the rules here?  Would it always be a _single_ digit followed by zero or more non digits?

Comment: No more specific rules, just random input. I forgot to mention, the first character will ALWAYS be a digit. So if there are no more digits, put the whole string in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex should do

```
const parts = '1fw3fe.w6=3\657'.match(/\d[^\d]*/g)
```

```js
const parts = String.raw`1fw3fe.w6=3\657`.match(/\d[^\d]*/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Comment: @AGamePlayer where does your data comes from?

Comment: Not in a real case, just thinking....